# Safe Area increase itself after hide tab bar, but dont decrease if i show tab bar again

Tags: swift, safearealayoutguide

i have a view controllers in a tab bar controller with constraints to bottom safe area, but one of them i must hide tab bar i use this
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
this increase the safe area

But if i need to move to another i show back tab bar
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
But safe area don't decrease by itself, making view contents behind tab bar

To make it clear i put a red view pinned to bottom safe area, next i go to view and hide tab bar
[image]

this is when it come back to this view and show tab bar again, safe area increased below tab bar, that's why red square are more below
[image]

Comment: are you using safeAreaInsets ? Those are just inset values it is best to use `safeAreaLayoutGuide`. Use the anchors

Comment: If you want to hide the tab bar when pushing another view controller onto the navigation controller (e.g. showing details of a particular item) you may set nextVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true before pushing the VC and the job will be done automatically without breaking the safe area configuration.

Comment: did you ever solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug in iOS. SafeArea doesn't change to account for tabBar, after hiding / showing it.

You can work around it by anchoring your view to superview and adjusting for tabBar manually. For example, if you want to anchor a tableView to a tabBar it would look like this

```
    if let tabBar = tabBarController?.tabBar {
        tabBar.isHidden = true
        tableViewBottomConstraint.constant = tabBar.frame.height
    }
```

Comment: This solution will probably not work perfectly on iPhone X.